# Intuition behind second derivative test for stationary points

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Doesn't second derivative only tell you whether the slope is increasing or decreasing after the point at x. How do you know if the slope before x is increasing or decreasing, and hence how do you tell a stationary point is maxima or minima just be the second derivative?

Answer (score 1):

For a function that is continuous, and the first derivative is continuous, and the limit of the second derivative when you approach point $x$ from **both** below and above is the same, the second derivative will tell you how slope changes in an infinitesimally  small interval before and after $x$. You can tell what the slope was doing before $x$, at $x-\epsilon$ by using $$f'(x-\epsilon)=f'(x)-\epsilon f''(x)$$

But the information just from second derivative is not enough. First the function at that point must have the first derivative equal to zero. For example $f(x)=x^2$ has the second derivative $f''(x)=2$. The slope is always increasing with $x$. But has only one extremum at $x=0$, where $f'(x)=0$